# Connect several web services with same object type

Tags: web-services, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I want to connect several webservices that share common object types. Using the internal tool from VS in the GUI: Add Service Reference… is not an option because it leads to several definitions of the same class types because of the different namespaces.

I tried the command line wsdl:

wsdl /sharetypes /language:CS /namespace:MyNameSpace /out:references.cs /protocol:SOAP http://AddressWS1?wsdl http://AddressWS2?wsdl http://AddressWS3?wsdl

this works, but I am a bit confused because I am used to work with the “app.config” file that does not exist here.

I also tried:
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out: references.cs /config:app.config http://AddressWS1?wsdl http://AddressWS2?wsdl http://AddressWS3?wsdl

it does not work as I get several errors of the type: “The global element xxx has already been declared.”

Is there a better solution?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just because they appear to you (the developer) as the same shapes, the fact that they are in different namespaces, means that they ARE actually different and must be treated as such.

It's entirely possible that if you get your idea to work, one of the WebServices then decides to add another field to its response, but not the others, and then you have to split them again.

Comment: thanks for your answer. by the "different name spaces", I meant that when using the tool from VS "Add Service Reference", i have to do it for each webservice separately and to choose each time a different namespace.
From the webservices side, the objects are the same. From my project, I actually see a definition of ObjectA in the context of service1 and another in the context of service2...

Comment: with the "wsdl" command line, i am abble to generate the proxy class without dupplicate of the same objects, but i would prefer to continue working with the app.config file. svcutil.exe would be better, but I cannot make it work as indicated in my problem.